# How can I call two controller one after another in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

We have to load two controller from an another controller class.

The source is like this:

```
   public function index()
{


             /** Laodning the Twitter Controller for the Twitter Feed **/

            $this->load->controller('twitter', 'twitter_controller');
            $data['twitter_feed'] = $this->twitter_controller->fetchAll();

            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($data['twitter_feed']);
            echo '</pre>';


            /** Loading the News Controller to get the Latest News **/

            $this->load->controller('news', 'news_controller');
            $data['news'] = $this->news_controller->get_latest_news();
```

The twitter controller is getting loaded but not able to load the news controller.

Comment: Isn't it better calling the controllers from the page itself using AJAX when you need some portion of the page needed data from another controller?

Comment: I'd use Models for that purpose. Then you can resuse that in as many controllers functions as required.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redirect function instead, try

```
redirect("controller_name/function_name","refresh");//this code is using header function of php, it simple get the base_url+1st parameter.
```

hope this will help you